# Why isn't my loop reaching the end of the file?

Tags: c, loops, visual-studio-2012, file-io, struct

I am building an application in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8.1 that uses linear regression to calculate/predict the world population at a certain year in time. The data is being read in from a text file and the program uses the data to calculate linear regression.

Text file contents:

```
0.001 0.200
1.000 0.310
1.500 0.450
1.650 0.500
1.750 0.791
1.800 0.978
1.850 1.262
1.900 1.650
1.927 2.000
1.950 2.519
1.955 2.756
1.960 2.982
1.965 3.335
1.970 3.692
1.975 4.068
1.980 4.435
1.985 4.831
1.990 5.263
1.995 5.674
2.000 6.070
2.005 6.454
2.008 6.707
2.009 6.800
```

The issue I am having is that when I loop through the file to store the data in an array of structs, I get an exception before I can fully read the file.

This is the function I'm having issues with:

```
int ReadFile(char* filename) {
    char line[20];
    int i = 0;
    int recordCount = 0;
    FILE* file = NULL;
    Population* wp[] = {0};

    file = fopen(filename, "r"); /* open text file for reading */
    if (file != NULL) {
        printf("FILE OPENED FOR READING\n");
        while (fgets(line, 20, file) != NULL) {
            fscanf(file, "%s", line);
            recordCount++;
        }
        fclose(file);
        printf("There are %d records.\n\n", recordCount);
        //*wp = (Population*)malloc(sizeof(Population) * recordCount);
        file = fopen(filename, "r");
        for (i = 0; i < recordCount; i++) {
            wp[i] = (Population*)malloc(sizeof(Population));
            fscanf(file, "%5f", &wp[i]->year);
            printf("%f ", wp[i]->year);
            fscanf(file, "%5f", &wp[i]->population);
            printf("%f\n", wp[i]->population);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 1;
}
```

The final for loop (the one where I malloc space for the struct) is the one that crashes my program. I can get about 3 iterations before it crashes on the 4th one.

Exception thrown:

```
First-chance exception at 0x7741D7E0 (ntdll.dll) in worldpopulation.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x871EADD7.
Unhandled exception at 0x7741D7E0 (ntdll.dll) in worldpopulation.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x871EADD7.
```

The exception seems to be caused by the file pointer becoming corrupted, but I have no idea why. Can anybody help me figure out why the last loop causes a crash? Thanks!

Comment: Why is the first malloc commented out?

Comment: you never allocate for the actual array.  Try this: `Population* wp[2000];` see if yo still get the error.

Comment: @Hogan That was indeed the issue, but I got it to work using a double pointer. The initial size was supposed to be `recordCount` but because it is a variable I could not use it as a size. But +1 for helping me isolate the issue.

Comment: In C there is no difference between `x *var[];` and `x **var;` except the what syntax C lets you use.

Comment: I'm fairly new to C programming and still do not fully understand pointers and dynamic memory. But I will definitely keep that in mind.

Comment: regarding these lines: while (fgets(line, 20, file) != NULL) {
            fscanf(file, "%s", line);  the first line is reading the first line of the file, the second line is reading the second line of the file.  so the code is only working on every other line, however, as a side note, the format parameter to the fscanf() needs to have a leading ' ' so white space is skipped over. otherwise it will be blocked by the '\n' at the end of the line.  Things will go very wrong from there forward.  Suggest removing the fscanf() line from the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (fgets(line, 20, file) != NULL) {
    fscanf(file, "%s", line);
    recordCount++;
```

You are reading twice and counting once. First using `fgets` and then using `fscanf`. I am guessing you want to get rid of the `fscanf`.

An additional problem is:

```
Population* wp[] = {0};
[...]
wp[i] = (Population*)malloc(sizeof(Population));
```

It is illegal to access anything other than `wp[0]`. Again, I am guessing you want to allocate something like:

```
Population** wp = malloc(recordCount * sizeof *wp);
```

---

The way you are reading the file twice is not efficient. You should do the `fscanf`s the first time around and grow `wp` as needed with `realloc`.

Comment: @cricutar -- realloc is slow.  Esp. since the code counts the lines.

Comment: @Hogan Are you sure amortised `realloc` (double the size every time) is slower than doing extra system calls (extra opens, reads and closes) and extra parsing ?

Comment: I see your point -- you are saying don't count the lines first, remove that part and use realloc if needed.  I agree with that point.

Comment: @cnicutar After a bit of fiddling around fixing the double pointer and removing the array declaration, I got it to produce my desired output. Much appreciated! +1